# How to use mySQL view and UPDATE to change a table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Almost a complete rookie with mySQL, but I will try to explain what I have done so far as clearly as possible.

So I created a view in mySQL using the following data. This returns back details of members who were born in the current month. I have named it birthdays_thismonth.

```
SELECT member.member_id,CONCAT(person.firstname,' ', person.surname) AS 'Member Name', 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,member.registration_date)/365) AS 'Years Member For', person.DOB
FROM person
JOIN member ON member.person_id = person.person_id AND MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Now, using this data, I want to be able to update the members table with a column that is named "birthday_discount".

I am having trouble getting the query done, as it seems to not like the fact that I am trying to update something that the select query is pulling from.

```
update member SET member.birthday_discount = 'b'
WHERE member.member_id IN
(SELECT member.member_id FROM member
INNER JOIN birthday_thismonth ON member.member_id = birthday_thismonth.member_id)
```

It seems like I am trying to read from member too much, and it is getting confused, but I cannot work out a way to do it from research. Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated, as the individual queries work fine, just not when put together. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't try, but i suggest to replace the `IN` by `=`

Comment: I would get rid of the view. It's distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a correlated subquery or `join`:

```
update member m join
       birthday_thismonth btm
       on m.member_id = btm.member_id
    set m.birthday_discount = 'b';
```